# Disabling Downloads on Jupyter Notebooks

Tags: python, security, jupyter

My goal is to disable the downloading of csv data from my JupyterHub environment. Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You wish to block only .csv or in general all files ?

Comment: @Emmanuel-Lin all files in general.

Comment: https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter/issues/293

Answer (score 3):

Since v3.1.0 you can disable downloads using labextension:

```
# disable downloads from File > Download
jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:download
# disable downloads from the context menu in the file browser
jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/filebrowser-extension:download
```

original github issue: https://github.com/jupyterlab/jupyterlab/issues/5274

Answer (score 1):

i have done this by removing download functionality from the source code, there are packages folder which contains the extensions related to file browser in each type script file in src i have commented the code for download, upload, Export Notebook As etc according to my client needs.

can refer my GitHub page for dev_mode folder. copy the dev_mode folder of mine and jupyter in dev mode from my folder

```
https://github.com/Shrikantgrh/JupyterLab-DownloadUploadDisabled
```

Answer (score 1):

I have achieved this by putting Jupyter Hub behind ALB (Application load balancer), AWS and have a rule that basically routes every request with path "/files" to a 503 error page. This can even be achieved using nginx as well. Just to bear that in mind, the download request path is "/files".

Comment: I followed the instructions in jupyterhub documentation by installing them via helm. I created an ingress nginx in k8 and routing all the "/files" to a blackhole backend. Unfortunately, it did not work. The user still able to download the files.. :(