# Disable download in Jupyter Hub (TLJH)

Tags: python, jupyter, jupyterhub

I'm trying to disable the option of downloading files and notebooks from an internal (available over LAN) [jupyterhub setup](https://tljh.jupyter.org/en/latest/install/custom-server.html).

I've [seen other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69158406/4872065) where answers shared are probably specific to Jupyter notebook and not Jupyter hub? Is there a way to apply those configurations to jupyterhub?

`jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/docmanager-extension:download`
`jupyter labextension disable @jupyterlab/filebrowser-extension:download`

Comment: It looks like  instead of "specific to Jupyter notebook", you mean "specific to JupyterLab"? And [the answer is at that it is at done at the level of the Juyter interface](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/remove-or-disable-download-options-in-jupyterhub/6782/2?u=fomightez). That is why where you reference spells out doing it that way.